# Unrecognized selector sent to instance Swift 3

Tags: ios, swift3, xcode8, uitapgesturerecognizer, unrecognized-selector

I want to implement `TapGestureRecognizer` with the `selector`, below is the code where I added tapGestureRecognizer to my `imageView`

```
let tapFirstGestureRecognizer = UITapGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(assignImage(_:)))
firstImageView.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
firstImageView.tag = 1
firstImageView.addGestureRecognizer(tapFirstGestureRecognizer)
```

Here is the action method

```
func assignImage(_ sender: UIImageView){
    imagePicker.allowsEditing = false
    imagePicker.sourceType = .photoLibrary
    imageViewTag = sender.tag

    present(imagePicker, animated: true, completion: nil)
}
```

Compiler keeps saying

> [UITapGestureRecognizer tag]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x6080001a7700'

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The problem is with your method declaration and with assigning `tag` to the object of `UIGestureRecognizer`. Change your method declaration like this.

```
func assignImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer)
```

Or

```
func assignImage(_ sender: UIGestureRecognizer)
```

**Edit:** To access imageView object with `UITapGestureRecognizer`.

```
func assignImage(_ sender: UITapGestureRecognizer) {
    if let imageView = sender.view as? UIImageView {

    }
}
```

**Note:** You need to set `tag` with you `imageView` not with you `UITapGestureRecognizer`

Comment: I want to pass imageView as a parameter to get its tag

Comment: That not possible, but you can access that `imageview` object using `sender.view as? UIImageView`.

Comment: Okay I will now try it

Comment: @aatalyk Please also check the latest edited answer,

Comment: Okay it says to wait some minutes)